# "Bookmark" button?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there anything like a bookmark button using Javascript or HTML or PHP that we can bookmark the website ? without doing manually.

Like,

When the user clicks the button.The webpage should automatically bookarmed by the browser.

Thanks

Comment: Good lord, I *hope not.* That'd open up a hellish security risk (**any** website would be automatically able to bookmark itself without user input...). Also, I suspect that bookmarking would occur outside of the browser's 'sandbox,' and in the 'chrome' of the broswer itself (I'm not sure what the correct terms are, which is why they're quoted).

Comment: This used to be possible in IE, but there is no cross-browser way to do this

Comment: You could consider adding buttons that link to social bookmarking services on your site.

Answer (score 4):

Not really. There used to be some hacks for *some* browsers, but I doubt they still work.

If a user knows how to find and follow an existing bookmark (which is what you really want), he will also know how to add it with his browser feature.